# Como pegar uma data com JavaScript e inserir num form input hidden?

Tags: javascript

Preciso que o javascript preencha automaticamente em um `<input type="hidden" />` com a data atual, e outro com 15 dias após a data atual.

Será usado para data de emissão de um boleto e o outro para a data de vencimento do boleto, e preciso que o formato seja `aaaammdd`.

```
<input name="dataEmissao" type="hidden" />
<script>
   ????????????????
</script>
```

e

```
<input name="dataVencimentoTit" type="hidden" />
<script>
    ????????????????
</script>
```

> Obs: não pode ser PHP, pois estou usando este código dentro de um code
>   block do theme, no WordPress. Lá dentro não funciona código PHP, só
>   JavaScript.

Comment: Qual o formato que queres dar à data? yyyymmdd?

Comment: O vencimento deveria ser feito no lado que gera boleto, e não do form. Na verdade, se é wordpress hospedado, poderia sim fazer com PHP, e normalmente não é o tema o lugar melhor pra isso.

Comment: O Sicoob me mandou um exemplo que o campo vencimento é enviado via post. Também não concordo, mas exigem o preenchimento deste input. :/

Comment: @RafaelT dá uma olhada aqui:https://jsfiddle.net/74Ly8gbx/ é isso que procuras?

Comment: Então... é que preciso colocar este código em um local específico dentro do tema... não sei pq não está interpretando php la dentro...

Comment: o formado precisa ser yyyymmdd

Comment: @RafaelT pior que até o google faz umas coisas dessas em nome "do padrão". Mesmo assim, se pudesse gerar pelo PHP seria melhor. De qq forma, em JS nao é complicado. Vamos aguardar resposta.

Comment: Funcionou... só o formato que esta vindo assim "Mon Jun 13 2016 12:52:12 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)"

Comment: @Sergio, só falta o formato yyymmdd. Muito obrigado por enquanto!!!

Comment: @RafaelT juntei uma resposta com isso. Carrega a página de novo...

Comment: @Sergio Deu algo errado... o resultado para data atual deu "2016413".. preciso também que o mês tenha dois dígitos.. o certo seria "20160613"

Comment: @RafaelT tens razão corrigi: https://jsfiddle.net/3zymmpxb/1/

Comment: @Sergio Perfeito! MUITO OBRIGADO!!!!

Comment: @Sergio Amigo, abusando... preciso diminuir o tempo para 10 dias. Você mandou 1296e6 para 15 dias... não sei fazer esta conta... pode passar o novo valor para 10 dias por favor? Mais uma vez obrigado!

Comment: @RafaelT é só contar a partir de milisegundos. `10(dias) x 24(h) x 60(m) x 60(s) x 1000`, ou seja: `864000000` que encurtado pode ser `864e6`.

Comment: @Sergio muito obrigado mais uma vez. Abraço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como fazer setar uma data num input e outra, quinze dias depois noutro?

Os passos que precisas seguir são:

- criar um objeto data com o dia de inicio
- criar um novo objeto data com mais `1296e6` ms que o outro (porque o JavaScript trabalha em milisegundos)
- ter uma função para formatar a string de saída, neste caso `YYYYMMDD`
- ir ao DOM "buscar" os elementos e setar o seu `.value`

Na prática:

```
function pad(s) {
    return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s;
}

function formatarData(d) {
    return [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() - 1, d.getDate()].map(pad).join('');
}

var emissao = document.querySelector('input[name="dataEmissao"]');
var vencimento = document.querySelector('input[name="dataVencimentoTit"]');

var hoje = new Date();
var quinzeDias = new Date(hoje.getTime() + 1296e6);
emissao.value = formatarData(hoje);
vencimento.value = formatarData(quinzeDias);
```

### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/3zymmpxb/1